# Core Data Fetch is Returning Nothing

Tags: sqlite, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

In this app, I am using an sqlite database that was created by another app. I can query the database using the Firefox SQLite Manager and see that what I am searching for does exist in the database. I have reduced my query to something very simple, but still get nothing returned in my NSFetchedResultsController.

Here is my code:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController*) frc {

    if (!frc_) {
        @autoreleasepool {

            NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
            NSEntityDescription * entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"INDEX" inManagedObjectContext:[ManagedObjectContext moc]];
            [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
            [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:15];

            NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"lemma = 'dog'"];

            [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:nil];
            [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

            NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"lemma" ascending:YES];
            NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, nil];
            [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

            NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController =
            [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
             initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
             managedObjectContext:[ManagedObjectContext moc]
             sectionNameKeyPath:@"lemma"
             cacheName:nil];

            aFetchedResultsController.delegate = (id<NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>)self;

            NSError *error = nil;

            if (![aFetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Unresolved Error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                abort();
            }
            self.frc = aFetchedResultsController;
        }
    }

    return frc_;

}
```

There is an entity called "INDEX" in the data model. To confirm that the entity has the `lemma` property, I show the content of its `lemma` property, getting this:

```
po [[entity propertiesByName] objectForKey:@"lemma"]

(id) $3 = 0x1104f740 (<NSAttributeDescription: 0x1104f740>), name lemma, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity INDEX, renamingIdentifier lemma, validation predicates (
), warnings (
), versionHashModifier (null)
 userInfo {
}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null)
```

Examining the contents of the `aFetchedResultsController` immediately after the fetch (where it is assigned to self.frc) gives this:

```
po aFetchedResultsController
(NSFetchedResultsController *) $4 = 0x1105c5c0 <NSFetchedResultsController: 0x1105c5c0>

po [[aFetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count]
(id) $1 = 0x00000000 <nil>
```

I suppose the problem here is something very basic, but I don't know what I am overlooking.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer at the [Ray Wenderlich site](http://www.raywenderlich.com/980/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data). The problem is that the sqlite file must be moved from the application bundle to the application documents directory.

This is done by copying it form the bundle into the documents directory if it is not already there.

Here is the code for creating the persistent store coordinator:

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)pstore {
    if (pstore_ != nil) {
        return pstore_;
    }
    NSString *storePath     = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"words.sqlite"];
    NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: storePath];

    // THIS IS THE KEY PIECE TO IMPORTING AN EXISTING SQLITE FILE:
    // Put down default db if it doesn't already exist
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:storePath]) {
        NSString *defaultStorePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                      pathForResource:@"words" ofType:@"sqlite"];
        if (defaultStorePath) {
            [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultStorePath toPath:storePath error:NULL];
        }
    }


    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption, 
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];

    NSError *error = nil;
    pstore_ = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:self.mom];
    if(![pstore_ addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                              configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:options error:&error]) {
        // Error for store creation should be handled in here
    }

    return pstore_;
}
```